# Delegate events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, controls

This is a C# question. I have a user control A. A contains another user control B. B has an event called BEvent. I want to expose this event in A so anyone who uses control A can subscribe BEvent. How can I write code to implement this design? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside your user control A you could expose the event of control B like this...

```
public event EventHandler EventA
{
    add { _control.EventB += value; }
    remove { _control.EventB -= value; }
}
```

You should look at the delegate which event B is using, and ensure that event A matches. In this example i just selected EventHandler because that is quite common when developing User Controls

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Comment: I assume what you'd want is EventHandler<SomeType> where SomeType matches EventB.

Comment: Taylor L, i have updated my answer, all you need is matching delegates